# Proportion or (adjusted) count variable as regression predictor with varying denominators

Tags: regression, proportion, bias, predictor

I am attempting to run various different regression models for different health outcomes (i.e., ordered logit for self-rated health, Cox models for survival). My predictor variable is quality of care as measured by a number of indicators, and so I am attempting to assess the association between improved quality of care (passing more quality indicators) and health outcomes. There are 39 quality indicators, but not all patients are eligible to respond to all of them and therefore each patient in my sample has between 1 and 39 indicators (with approx. half of patients only eligible for 1 indicator). Given that, what is a better independent variable in the model: (1) the proportion of indicators passed; (2) the count variable for indicators passed (including the denominator in the equation to adjust for this???); or (3) some other method I'm not aware of? When half the sample is only eligible for one indicator and therefore the proportion of indicators passed is either 0% or 100%, would this introduce bias? If you could point me in the direction of the limitations of each of these approaches I would appreciate it.